# Joining a company to work on a similar product to my own company

Tags: new-job, negotiation

I have a (startup) company. It's a marathon project with a few years to fruition so I decided to join others in the meantime. At the very least I have a day-to-day company but startups rarely succeed so that's my lifeboat.

I'm likely going to be given an offer in a company on a project that is similar to what I'm doing. That's great because my skills are directly translated and I know their future since my product is more developed and I have more experience than all people on their team. They do have, however, advantage that they already have customers and they're an addition to the main product and the domain is a "experimental".

**I'd like to keep my company and the product. How and what should I negotiate in the offer?**

It's a software solution. There are many components in total, including things that are already open sourced, components that are unrelated and things that are (likely) identical.

I'm happy to give more details although I'm intentionally leaving question broad.

Comment: Does this company you want to join do work that is so similar to what you want to do with your startup that copyright issues could arise? Why don't you search for investors to fund your startup which would allow you to work full time on that and allow you to hire employees instead?

Comment: Does the hiring company know you are already developing a competing product? It sounds like you're setting yourself up for a lot of legal trouble in the future.

Comment: @user1666620 it's less money issue and more collaboration issue. There is a lot of things to do and I estimate that it's going to be at least half a year before getting any customer. I'm worried about the daunting loneliness that I already experienced. Basically, I want the product to be out there and I want to make sure it's done. I know how things can change in companies so I need to be sure that I can work to push it myself in the worst case scenario.

Comment: @SethR Yes, from the very beginning I've been open with them. It's even in my resume at the top. I've passed interviews because they asked open questions to which I have already implemented answer from my product. Everyone is aware.

Comment: @DawidLaszuk A half year until customers isn't terrible and honestly if you're that close then searching for investors will help by also providing advice and cash. Otherwise you're just wasting your time doing something other than growing your business. Also, investors will let you know if your product even has a market.

Comment: @user1666620 it may seems like it isn't but to me it is. Doing everything myself is draining and then I don't have people to share experience with. I'm an expat in Canada with friends not in my domain. Meetups are hits'n'miss and covid showed how much community I need. If there were others working with me - sure. On my own it's super difficult and I don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

The way that people normally handle this is to disclose and acknowledge (in a document signed by both you and the employer) that the work was done prior to your employment and they disclaim any rights to it. In some companies, such disclosure is standard, in others, you can ask for a form and they'll usually accommodate you.

After you stop working at your employer, it is generally okay to work on your project, but you are not supposed to base it too much on the stuff you did for your previous employer. You cannot for example memorize proprietary algorithms from your paid work, quit, and immediately incorporate them into your own product. This will probably be spelled out in your contract, but even if not, there are often laws about it. You'd probably want a lawyer to help you figure out exactly where to draw the line on how much *after* quitting you should wait and how close can your own product be. Your situation complicates things, because you cannot claim you got the idea for your company *after* you left, since it already exists.

Developing your similar product *while* working is a no no. Firstly, many companies have contracts that automatically give them ownership of IP you produce. Typically these exempt things developed in your own time, that are unrelated to the company's business. Getting a job at a company to see how their product works and copying it is basically industrial espionage and will get you sued easily. It will be very difficult for you to prove that your product is your own invention and not just ideas stolen from your employer, given that it's the same type of product. The only way to pull this off (eg. done by consultants who work with several similar companies at once) is to have a very detailed IP/trade secret section in the employment contract. Because of the complexity of the matter, it is very unlikely that this can be written without a lawyer, and the company's lawyer probably won't bother because it's easier to hire people who don't run competing companies.

As a simple thought experiment, imagine that while working full time on your company, you hire an assisstant to do some work. One day the assisstant quits and starts his own company that copies your product and takes away your business. Would you feel this is fair? Most <s>people</s> lawyers wouldn't.

Your best option is to work only at your own company. You can try to look for investors, loans or opportunities to have *your company* be employed by others for some related tasks. With the last option, you'll still have to pay a lawyer for the contract, but it's more realistic to have a deal that works.

The second best option is to work a day job that is as unrelated as possible. For example, if you are a waiter at a bakery, nobody will claim that your 3D game engine company stole secrets from your employer. If your product and job are both in software, you are already taking a risk, but it should at least be a very different area of software. So (recalling the same example), work on accounting software for an insurance company rather than a game studio.

Of course, you should not take this post at face value and consult with a lawyer for specific legal advice.

Answer (score -3):

Why would you negotiate anything? Hire an attorney to make sure that your intellectual property is legally protected. Then don't discuss it at all unless it comes up as a condition of their hiring you.

If it does come up then let them know that your intellectual property isn't negotiable. If that's a deal breaker for them then walk away. You have the same legal rights to your intellectual property as they do to theirs. Negotiating my intellectual property isn't something that I'd even consider.

Comment: Seems there's some misunderstanding. Maybe I don't understand your answer. I'm not referring to what I've done so far. That's mine. I'm asking about possibility to work on my company in my free time whilst working for the new company.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, that's the intention with negotiations. I'm now drawing a plan on what to expect from their side and how to present my case to retain as much leverage in the future. E.g. I'm not singing anything that will expend beyond my employment like cannot offer my product X months after leaving the company.

Comment: Not discussing it is a bad idea.  You'll want something in writing that assures you can continue working on your own product without it being seen as a conflict or interest or give them a claim to the IP.  "What they don't know can't hurt them" doesn't hold up in a copyright lawsuit.